# Как раскодировать файл docx из json?

Tags: javascript, json, http

На http запрос я получаю следующий JSON:

```
{
 "file":"UEsDBBQACAgIAGhSO08AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAARAAAAd29yZC9kb2N1bWVudC54bWztnd1u20Yahs99FQTPY0q27NhC7MKbOGkXdqq1vQV6ZFDUSGLDPwxHstWjNO1iF0iBnuz5bu8gDeqtt167t0De0X4zpCgqhhXJcmxRem1AmuH8PDPDGfL9vqGkJ5+duo7WZTy0fW9LLy+XdI15lt+wvdaW/tej54829M+2l56cVBu+1XGZJ5Y0KuGF1S7b0ttCBFXDCK02c81w2Q+YR4lNn7umoChvGa7JX3WCR5bvBqaw67Zji56xUi.......",
 "typeOfReport": "docxTest"
}
```

В поле file закодирован документ docx. Как мне правильно принимать данный json чтобы получить файл. Возможно ли это?

Comment: Декодируйте поле `file` из Base64.

Comment: @Yaant, все равно не пойму. Вот я принял этот json, распарсил, декодировал file, а потом как мне его отобразить в интерфейсе или скачать

Comment: Для начала, где Вы этот JSON получаете, в браузере или на сервере?

Comment: @Yaant, в браузере

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4184944/javascript-download-data-to-file-from-content-within-the-page